# How can I save or set state on a Button

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to know how to change or keep the state of a button since it got clicked, I'm a beginner on android/Kotlin and only found answer in java code.

I tried everything like that, no one worked out :

```
val buttonChart: Button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonChart)
    buttonChart.isSelected
```

Comment: Welcome on SO ! Can you [edit] your question to explain why this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a MaterialComponents theme (which is the default for new projects), then Buttons in your layout are actually MaterialButtons, which have the extra feature of being "checkable", meaning it can have a checked/not-checked state.

To be able to visually see if it's checked or not, you probably want to give it a tint color that adapts to the checked state. This is done with a [color state list resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource). Here's an example one you can use. Put it in the `res/color` directory, which you might have to create first.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:color="?attr/colorPrimary"  />
</selector>
```

In the layout editor, set `checkable` to true for the button, and set `buttonTint` to the color file we created above with `@color/whatever_you_named_the_file`.

In your Kotlin code, you can cast the button to a MaterialButton to see whether it is checked, for example:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    if ((it as MaterialButton).isChecked) {

    } else {

    }
}
```